# Is every  group object in TopMan a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Recall that a *Lie group* is a group object in the category of *C*<sup>∞</sup> manifolds.

If I have a group object in the category of topological manifolds, can I necessarily equip it with a smooth structure so that all the group operations are smooth?  If so, how unique is this structure?

Is a continuous group-homomorphism between two Lie groups necessarily smooth?

Comment: This is exactly Hilbert's fifth problem, which is summarized reasonably in Wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fifth_problem


Comment: The best there is, if I recall correctly, is that a locally compact topological group such that the identity has a neighborhood which does not contain a subgroup can be smoothed to an analytic manifold in a unique way so that it becomes an analytic Lie group. There was an article in the AMS Notices recently about Gleason, with interesting details about the history of this result

Comment: @GK: I think what you wrote should have been an answer and not a comment (it answers the question, doesn't it?).  I took the liberty of essentially repeating your answer below.  We'll see what happens.

Comment: @Greg: Oh, ok.  Really, you should put that as an answer, so I can mark the question as answered :)  Otherwise, I'll just close the question as no longer relevant.

Comment: What I had in mind is that we should freeze or community-wiki questions that exactly match Wikipedia pages.  MO should go beyond Wikipedia.


Comment: @Greg: That's fair.  I wouldn't have known to google for "Hilbert's fifth problem", though, and there is not a link to it from the Wikipedia page on Lie groups.  I almost closed the question as "no longer relevant", but it seems that we can only make actions once every 30 seconds, and by then Pete had responded.

Comment: Let me suggest that you still c-wiki it, and maybe change the question to whether there is some new direction for Hilbert's 5th problem that is not mentioned in Wikipedia.


Comment: I think I disagree with the idea that if it's on Wikipedia then it's not a good MO question.  Wikipedia is a currently voluminous, only mostly correct, and potentially limitless repository of mathematical knowledge.  The idea of MO, I think, is that what you are wondering about might be easy or -- better yet -- already known to some other mathematician.  I think Theo's question is fine.

Comment: Pete:  I guess I can see both sides of the issue.  On the one hand, people could ask standard Wikipedia questions forever:  What is Rokhlin's theorem, when is Hausdorff dimension different from box-counting dimension, etc.  On the other hand, many Wikipedia pages are underdeveloped or flawed, and actually MO could be used to improve them.  This question is somewhere in this middle.


Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Greg Kuperberg indicated in the comments, this is Hilbert's 5th Problem.  The answer is yes, a theorem of Gleason, Montgomery and Zippin from the 1950's.

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to add that there is a fairly easy proof for your final question:  Is every continuous homomorphism between Lie groups actually smooth?

The theorem we need is the closed subgroup theorem (also called the [Cartan Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_subgroup)): If H is a topologically closed subgroup of a Lie group G, then H is actually an embedded Lie subgroup.

Granting this, one proves all continuous homomorphisms are smooth as follows:

Given Lie groups H and G with $f:H\rightarrow G$ a continuous homomorphism, consider the subgroup $K$ of $H\times G$ given by the graph of $f$.  The graph is a closed subset of $H\times G$ precisely because $f$ is continuous, and hence, by the closed subgroup theorem, the graph is an embedded smooth submanifold of $H\times G$.  Thus, the restriction of the two canonical projection maps $\pi_1:H\times G\rightarrow H$ and $\pi_2:H\times G\rightarrow G$ are smooth when restricted to K.

Now, $\pi_1$ restricted to $K$ is clearly* a diffeomorphism onto $H$, and hence has a smooth inverse and so is smooth.  But then we find that $f = \pi_2\circ \pi_1^{-1}$ is a composition of smooth maps, and hence is smooth.  (To be clearer, the $\pi_1^{-1}$ means the inverse of $\pi_1:K\rightarrow H$.)

*- (Edited in due to comments).  One knows by Sard's theorem that there is a point $p\in K$ such that $d_p \pi_1$ is invertible (of full rank).  I claim that this implies that for all $q\in K$, $d_q \pi_1$ is invertible.  The point is that $\pi_1$ is group homomorphism, which is the same as saying $\pi_1\circ L_{qp^{-1}} = L_{\pi_1(qp^{-1})}\circ \pi_1$, where $L_g$ denotes left multiplication by $g: L_g(h) = gh$.  Taking the differentials at p on each side of this equation and using the chain rule, one finds

$$d_q \pi_1 \circ d_p L_{qp^{-1}} = d_{\pi_1(p)}L_{\pi_1(qp^{-1})}\circ d_p \pi_1.$$

The fact that $L_g$ is a diffeomorphism (with inverse $L_{g^{-1}}$) implies that $dL$ is invertible at any point, and hence we see that

$$d_q\pi_1 = d_{\pi_1(p)}L_{\pi_1{qp^{-1}}}\circ d_p \pi_1\circ d_pL_{pq^{-1}};$$ i.e., that $d_q \pi_1$ is a composition of invertible maps, and hence is itself invertible.

Comment: I think one needs a bit more argument to see that you get a diffeomorphism from $K$ to $H$: something like Sard's theorem to make sure the derivative bijects.

Comment: I'll clarify it....

Comment:  I just wanted to add that this also addresses the uniqueness question asked: A topological group has a unique smooth structure. For if we give G two smooth structures, then the identity map from G to itself is continuous, and hence by the above smooth. Since the identity map is its own inverse, this implies the identity map is a diffeomorphism between the two smooth structures.

Comment: To clarify my above comment, I mean IF a topological group has a smooth structure, then it's unique.