# Differential structures on compact Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Given a compact Lie group can there be a differential structure on it with respect to which one cannot define a smooth group operation?

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely not my expertise, but here is a stab at it.

A solution to [Hilbert's 5th Problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8793/is-every-group-object-in-topman-a-lie-group) states that given a topological group that is also a manifold there is a unique way to give it the structure of a Lie group.

On the other hand, there are [exotic structures](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/225910/exotic-smooth-structures-on-lie-groups?rq=1) on Lie groups (including compact ones).

So take a Lie group $G$ that admits an exotic structure.  Let $M$ denote the exotic version of $G$.  Then $G$ and $M$ are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.  However, if $M$ admitted a smooth group operation, then we contradict the *uniqueness part* of the solution to Hilbert's 5th Problem.

Comment: You don't need the full strength of Hilbert's 5th problem, just the simpler result that a continuous homomorphism between Lie groups is automatically smooth.

Comment: I think we do not need the full solution to Hilbert's 5t problem. It is elementary that a continuous homomorphism of Lie groups is automatically smooth. So a second countable locally Euclidean group can have at most one differentiable structure making it into a Lie group (cf. a book like Warner's). Any exotic structure on a Lie group will do, like you said. for instance in $R^4$.